# In Godus what do the two types of countdowns on buildings mean?

Tags: godus

The types I have in mind are:

[image: Example]

[image: Imgur]

The first kind of countdown is always on, the second is available by click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first count down is how long until that building has full occupancy. A full building can be tapped to send out a walker.

The second count down is how long until that building is finished being built.

Comment: What does it mean if the first countdown gets stuck?

Comment: I've had that as well, and can't find or figure out a reason for it. I believe it is just a bug.

Comment: It is either a bug or an uncompleted feature. In some builds of Godus, I've seen walker creation stop when there was nothing for a walker to do (ie, no new places to settle that a walker from that residence could reach, no items to build, etc) in the homeworld.